# unable to delete Steam cloud game data

Tags: games, steam, cloud, reset

I have recently attempted to play a game I have not played in a while, but had in-library, Portal Stories:Mel.

After re-downloading the game, it wouldn't start. The game would say it was running and then instantly sync and stop.

I have tried multiple things to try and fix this, including the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/943565/portal-2-wont-launch).
And this works, however, I can only play the game from the terminal, and the audio files do not play correctly.

I even tried to replicate the fix that was given for this on windows, by going into my /userdata/UID/AppID/remote/ folder and deleting the content of the documents inside, to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: If it wasn't clear, I wish to fully reset the cloud data on this particular game to it's original state, i.e. how it was when I first downloaded the game.

Comment: Have you tried going offline, deleted the local copy of the data, playing the game offline, and then going back on-line, and then starting the game again, choosing to prefer the local copy over the steam cloud version?

Comment: I attempted this, and It didn't recognize that the data was gone.
The game played-or didn't play-like normal. I had to use the console to open the game as well, as the library wouldn't open it. There was no conflict in the cloud. All I can think of is that I'm not changing the correct files